# playing .wav file with C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to play a .Wav file thats located in a folder inside my project.

The sound file is located on "Resource/Sounds/slot_roll_on.Wav"

The resource folder is a folder I created myself, in the root of the project.

This is the code I'm using to run the .wav file

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream s = a.GetManifestResourceStream("kisscam.g.resources.Resources.Sounds.slot_roll_on.wav");
        SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(s);
        snd.Play();
```

I couldn't get the sound to play, I keep getting the windows sound for sound not found.

Somewhere on stack overflow I found this code to find what the right assembly path should be.

```
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; i++)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(resourceNames[i]);


            }
```

It output these 2 paths

```
kisscam.Properties.Resources.resources
```

and

```
kissscam.g.resources
```

I tried using them both, but none of them works.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: Yeah sorry my english isen't very good. What don't you understand ?

Comment: Use ildasm.exe and look at the manifest of the assembly for the .mresource name.

Comment: it does not look like your WAV file is actually being added as a resource. Make sure the file is added to your project and the build action says "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't know about that! Now I still don't know what the proper path to it is.

Comment: @Spedax, I understand, try to format your question, it's just a practice here :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add your Wav file to resources by going to your Project Properties --> Resources Select Audio and Browse to the file. You will then be able to see it as part pf `Propeties.Resources`. It will add it to a Resources Folder where you can set it to embedded or leave it as is, which is set as content

[image]

Accessed like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer( Properties.Resources.tada);
    snd.Play();

}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add music in your program by playing your **.wav** file in projects. Then you have to add the **.wav** file like this.

```
   using System.Media; //  write down it at the top of the FORM

   SoundPlayer my_wave_file = new SoundPlayer("F:/SOund wave file/airplanefly.wav");
   my_wave_file.PlaySync(); // PlaySync means that once sound start then no other activity if form will occur untill sound goes to finish
```

Remember that you have to write the path of the file with **forward slashes** (/) format, don't use **back slashes** () during giving a path to the file, otherwise you will get an error

Answer (score 2):

Currently I know two ways to do so, see below:

1. **Use file path** 
   First put the file in the root folder of the project, then no matter you run the program under `Debug` or `Release` mode, the file can both be accessed for sure. Next use the class `SoundPlayer` to paly it.

   ```
       var basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
       SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
       player.SoundLocation = Path.Combine(basePath, @"./../../Reminder.wav");
       player.Load();
       player.Play();
   ```
2. **Use resource** 
   Follow below animate, add "Exsiting file" to the project.

[image]

```
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Reminder);
        player.Play();
```

The strength of this way compared to the other is:
Only the folder "Release" under the "bin" directory need to be copy when run the program.