# Including Media in Visual Basic Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, audio

So I want to include a .WAV file in my windows form.

I can get it to load and play, but when I open the application on another computer, there's an error.

I have been linking the .WAV file to a local folder (C:\Windows\Users and so on and so forth until I reach the file)

What changes need to be made so I can put the .WAV file in another place, and can you give some details on how to do so?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\RFair_000\Documents\Dropbox\School\Programs\Top Gun\Top Gun\Top Gun.wav")
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the file path to a config file or just keep it in the same directory or sub directory as the exe for easy reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [playing .wav file with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491431/playing-wav-file-with-c-sharp) answer is the same just remove the semi colons on the code for a vb.net equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Embed the file then you never have worry. Follow these instructions.[playing .wav file with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491431/playing-wav-file-with-c-sharp)